# Keeping consistent quality of marinated meat throughout the day in a restaurant

Tags: meat, marinade, serving, restaurant

The issue I need help with is knowing how to serve marinaded meats consistently to customers. I have found that for my recipe, the marinaded meats taste good after three hours of marinating. Of course, this is not possible to have the meals served after three hours consistently to patrons. For example, if I place the meats in the marinade at 6:00pm and start serving at noon the next day, they will have one texture and taste. If I start them in the morning, 9:00am, they are ready at noon.

Bottom line, what is the best practice for a food establishment that serves marinated meats on the menu (chicken, pork, lamb) without having different tastes and textures for patrons?

Comment: I've never had to deal with this issue, but if there are no other recommendations from knowledgeable people, you might try reducing the amount of acid and/or enzymatic tenderizers.  It might then require a longer marinde, but increase the window of when it's best to use.

Comment: It's called rotation of stock.  You must anticipate the demand of the product and have just the number that is required ready at that time.  So if you need 10 portions ready at ~6pm and 10 at ~7pm start 10 at 3pm and 10 at 4pm.

Comment: @jbarker2160 if you elaborate a bit more on the concept of rotation I think this would make a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is actually a more general topic under food quality.

The concept is either called stock rotation or just-in-time(for manufacturing).

You simply need to anticipate the need for the item and prepare it ahead of time, multiple times throughout the day.  If you need 10 portions an hour starting at 6pm, you need to begin marinating 10 portions at 3pm then 10 portions at 4pm and so on to satisfy your needs for the day.  Your work day begins when prep time must begin, not when your restaurant is open for customers.

Many restaurants do this with any product that doesn't hold well.  These items need to be prepared several times throughout service and rotation is a good way to do it.

Bakers don't go to work in the wee hours of the morning for no reason.  They do it to ensure their products are served at their peak of quality.

Comment: In particular, you can have all the marinade made already, and all the meat prepped, so all you have to do is quickly mix some up every hour.